Retrieving POST Data in PowerBi
I got access to a database through an API. There's two options I can use provided, one is a GET and the Other is a POST.
Looking at the GET API JSon body, it doesn't contain the information I need but the POST JSon does.
My goal is to extract this data into PowerBi to create reports. The difference between the two URLs is the POST has "run in it.
I don't have access to my work computer and I'm hoping to get this resolved over the weekend.
I was thinking of using Power Query and M Code but use the GET url and change the body code to what is in the POST request.
Do you think that would work or is there another way I can do this?

I tried using the POST URL and got a 405/401 error.

